# how do I use new App ID & secret ID without affect the existing access token

Tags: facebook, api, rest, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

First, I have use Facebook App ID & Secret ID, then Login with Facebook and get Access token,

I have changed the my Facebook App ID & Secret ID, but, affect the existing user Access token.

How do I get new Application Access token without Login with Facebook?

Comment: Simply put: This isn't working, because an Access Token is alsways bound to an App ID imho.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your App ID effectively means you've created a new application. Since the access_token is tried to a particular App ID and Secret combination, you cannot transfer existing users over to the new App ID. Furthermore, Facebook Platform Policies does not allow sharing of user information between different application - you'll just have to get users to login into the new application.